# humanized name for devise fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm going to make humanized name for Devise's each field by adding followings to User model:

```
HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
  :sex => "some_other_text",
  :age => "some_other_text"
}

def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES(attr.to_sym) || super
end
```

However, I'm getting error message saying...

```
undefined method `HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES' for #<Class:0x007f8201f39c80>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the hash incorrectly. It uses `[]` not `()`.

```
def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
end
```